# Develop universal app in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-universal-app

I want to develop universal application in iOS. But for now I am planning to upload only iPhone version of app on App Store and after some days I will upload iPad version.
My question is, Should i keep Devices as "Universal" or only "iPhone" for now?. If I keep "iPhone" now, Can I change it to "Universal" in future once my iPad app is ready to upload on App store.

Comment: yes you can change later on, keep it iPhone only for now, show that iPhone version didn't messed up on iPAD.

Comment: @sheshnath thank you for your response. Can you provide me some doc where i can read this and show to my client.

Comment: see this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html

Answer (score 1):

Creating Universal App Using Storyboard

When you first create a Xcode project, you’re provided with an option to define the supported devices. Choose “Universal” and Xcode will automatically create a project for all iOS devices.